# How can i fix the time zone issue in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, backend

I am using MERN structure, and when i am creating a new data from backend like this:

```
req.body.date = new Date()
```

this dates hour is must be 19:00 but inserted dates hour is 16:00.

How can i fix this issue?

I already tried 'mongoose-timezone' package.

Comment: You should save your time as UTC and later convert it into its correct format

Comment: `req.body.date = new Date(new Date().setHours(19,0,0,0))`.

Comment: MongoDB stores date as UTC time - **always and only**. You need to convert it to your local timezone within the client application.

Comment: thx but how can add 3 hour to my createdAt and updatedAt timestamps?

Comment: @RobG Am i wrong? This is just for specific date, can i use in model code? Like this:

member: String,
date: new Date(new Date().setHours(+3)) not exactly this but like this

Comment: No idea, never used MongoDB, I don't know if `req.body.date` is something you invented or specific to MongoDB. Your sample code assigns a *Date*, so that's what my comment does after setting the local time to 19:00:00.000. What data or object type should be assigned? If you want 19:00 UTC, then use `setUTCHours(19,0,0,0)`.